# Angular service is recreated and data is lost

Tags: angular

I created a small learning project in an effort to better understand dependency injection. Within my app, if I go back to root path (Home) the "DataService" lost the data. Why is that so?

I added the demo project to github and prepared a stackbliz link: https://stackblitz.com/github/TheAnonymousModeIT/AngularDITest

Steps to reproduce:

1. If you click on "update global service" data, the data in der service is going to be updated. You can see this at the labels.
2. If you go then to "Dashboard" (routerLink) than you see the updated data (the labels are the same)
3. Than go back to "Home" (and all labels are reset)

=> the data is gone

Why is that so?

Thx!

Comment: What's your basic goal? what you want to achieve? Do you want to share data across different components?

Comment: just playing around and learning. My goal is: I want to know why the service data gets reseted.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that in your component, you always initialize the data.

```
this.dataService.updateData("Initial Value (service from module level)");
```

before calling this method first check that data is empty or you do nothing.
Example:

```
if(!this.dataService.getData()) {
      this.dataService.updateData("Initial Value (service from module level)");
    } else {
      this.data = this.dataService.getData();
    }
```